# How to hide bottom border line in react native stack header?

Tags: css, react-native

I am making use of react navigation with a header. There is white line at the bottom of the header which when I changed the borderBottomWidth to 0, bake from think to a think line which sadly is still visible both on iOS and Android.

I tried a lot of solutions that I found on StackOverflow but nothing worked - elevation:0, shadowOpacity:0, height:0 and etc. Nothing worked. Any ideas how I can solve that issue?

Style:

```
    import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export const globalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display:'flex',
        backgroundColor: '#111111',
        flexDirection:'column',
        justifyContent:'space-evenly',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex:1,
    },
    header:{
        backgroundColor: '#111111',
        borderBottomWidth: 0,  
    },
   
    headerTitle:{
        fontFamily: "KoratakiLightItalic",
        fontSize:24
    },
    headerRight:{
        marginRight:10
    }
  
});
```

React Native Component:

```
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SettingsIcon from '../assets/SettingsIcon'

import {globalStyles} from '../styles/global'

const ChargingStack = createStackNavigator();

 function Charging() {
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text>Charging</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function ChargingStackScreen() {
  return (
    <ChargingStack.Navigator>
      <ChargingStack.Screen name="CHARGING" component={Charging} options={{ 
         headerRight: () => (
          <View style={globalStyles.headerRight}>
            <SettingsIcon />
          </View>
        ),
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerTitleStyle: globalStyles.headerTitle,
        headerStyle:  globalStyles.header
         }}/>
    </ChargingStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});
```

[image]

Comment: Is this on iOS or android? or both?

Comment: @dianaqqq it is both

Answer (score 2):

You need to set shadowColor to transparent in the stack navigator.

```
<Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#70AE97",
            shadowColor: "transparent",
          },
        }}
        initialRouteName="SettingsScreen"
      >
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solution that I have found until now has worked. What worked for me was to make the height of the header 80.

Comment: Not sure why but this works

Answer (score 0):

- Whether to hide the elevation shadow (Android) or the bottom border (iOS) on the header. Use

  **headerShadowVisible = false**

> ```
>  <Stack.Navigator
>                      screenOptions={{
>                        headerShown: true,
>                        headerShadowVisible: false
>                      }}
>                      initialRouteName="SettingsScreen"
>                    >
>              </Stack.Navigator>
> ```